# react component rendering infinite times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have App.js as the main class, and only MainChild inside of it.
Inside Mainchild I have some 10 other children in it where every each of them has an API call using useEffect and they just show some data.

The problem is that the Child1 gets re-rendering nonstop and that makes the children to make API calls nonstop as well, which messes up with my API and of course, the memory.

App.js:

```
import MainChild from './MainChild'
import React from 'react'
const App= React.memo(() => {
return (
console.log("test") //this console.log gets executed in every render, every second
<MainChild/>
 );
})
export default App;
```

MainChild:

```
import Child1 from './Child1'
import Child2 from './Child2'
import Child3 from './Child3'
import React from 'react'
const MainChild = () => {
return (

<Child1/>    
<Child3/>
<Child2/>
 );
}
export default MainChild;
```

Child1,child2,child3...child10:

```
useEffect(() => {
  
    fetch(configData.serverURL,{
      method:"POST",
      headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify({query: defTypedsQuery})
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        setIsLoaded(true);
        setItems(result.data.defTypedClasses);
      },
      (error) => {
        setIsLoaded(true);
        setError(error);
      }
    )
    
  const myValues = Object.values(state);
  setData(myValues)
  
}, [defTypedsQuery,setIsLoaded,setError,setItems])

if (error) {
  return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
} else if (!isLoaded) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
} else { 
return(
        <Select
        options={options}
        />
)
}
}
```

Now the thing is that everywhere I try (except App.js) a console.log, it will appear everywhere,every second. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are causing an infinite rerender due to your dependency array of useEffect. I believe that setIsLoaded,setError and setItems are recreated every render, so useEffect thinks that something changed.

```
 [defTypedsQuery,setIsLoaded,setError,setItems])
```

Change it to

```
//Only run first time and if defTypedsQuery changes
}, [defTypedsQuery])
```

Comment: Absolutely a life saver ! It works perfectly now, thank you very much. Much appreciated.

Comment: The above answer solves your problem but this is against the rules of hooks and the proper solution would be to move the fetch call in a separate function and call it from the useEffect

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb, I have tried to call the api with that method too, the call works all fine but I still needed to deal with re-rendering.

Comment: Agreed with @MuhammadHaseeb, a `useCallback` would be a better alternative instead of ignoring the required dependencies of the hook

Comment: when you have a separate function for that fetch call you dont need to add setIsLoaded,setError,setItems in the dependency array instead you just need to add the defTypedsQuery and that function name (where you have that call/logic) in the dependency array.
Also as mentioned by @Mentlegen useCallBack will serve the purpose here.